# Filtro CSS - Traer un texto al frente para que no se le aplique el filtro

Tags: css, filtro

> Tengo una imagen, y al pasar el mouse por encima de ella suceden dos cosas: Se muestra un texto animado y se aplica un filtro. El filtro se aplica a todos los elementos, pero yo quiero que no se aplique al texto. Probé con la propiedad `z-index` en distintos valores sin obtener resultados.

```
<ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-4@m uk-grid uk-grid-small" data-uk-height-viewport="">
  <li class="index-image uk-transition-toggle uk-animation-toggle overflow-hidden">

            <!-- Slider Image -->
            <img src="images\backgrounds\bg-13.jpg" alt="" data-uk-cover="">

            <!-- Overlay -->
            <div class="uk-position-cover">

                <!-- Overlay Content -->
                <div class="uk-position-bottom text-left padding-50px">
                    <div class="info-work uk-width-1-1@m uk-text-center uk-margin-auto uk-margin-auto-vertical">
                        <h1 class=" uk-animation-slide-right">Headline</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Overlay Content -->

            </div>
            <!-- End Overlay -->

        </li>
</ul>
```

> Y en css

```
li.index-image:hover {
    filter: opacity(.5);
}
```

> **Por otro lado, consulta extra:** El al hacer hover, el texto aparece con una animacion, pero al sacar el mouse de la imagen desaparece bruscamente. Hay alguna forma de manejar la transicion de salida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El modo más sencillo y lógico es aplicar el filtro únicamente a los elementos en los que quieras que aparezca al hacer `hover`. En el ejemplo se aplicaría sobre la imagen y el encabezado.

En cuanto a la segunda pregunta, una css asociada al evento `hover` deja de ejecutarse en el momento en que el evento no está activo, sería una pregunta diferente y habría que ver el código, pero quizás pudieras controlarlo mejor por `javascript`.

```css
li.index-image:hover img, li.index-image:hover h1 {
    filter: opacity(0.5);
}
```

```html
<ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-4@m uk-grid uk-grid-small" data-uk-height-viewport="">
  <li class="index-image uk-transition-toggle uk-animation-toggle overflow-hidden">

            <!-- Slider Image -->
            <img src="images\backgrounds\bg-13.jpg" alt="" data-uk-cover="">

            <!-- Overlay -->
            <div class="uk-position-cover">

                <!-- Overlay Content -->
                <div class="uk-position-bottom text-left padding-50px">
                    <div class="info-work uk-width-1-1@m uk-text-center uk-margin-auto uk-margin-auto-vertical">
                        <h1 class=" uk-animation-slide-right">Headline</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Overlay Content -->

            </div>
            <!-- End Overlay -->

        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

solo usa el filtro donde lo necesites,

```css
ejemplo: 
li:hover > img, li:hover h1 {opacity: .5;}
ejemplo:
li:hover :is(img, h1) {opacity: .5}
ejemplo:
li:hover {opacity: .5;}
li:hover p {opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).